# Multiple IF(AND) statements to determine Pass/Fail

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm using Google sheets to try to generate a Pass/Fail in a cell based on two different parameters;

If (R2) is less than 85% AND (I2) equals "T1","T2, or "T3" I need a fail generated.

similarly, for the same cell;

If (R2) is less than 95% AND (I2) equals "Broker Audit" I need a fail generated.

My issue is that if it's a Broker Audit and less than 95%, i need a fail generated. However, if it's a T1 T2 or T3 audit then it needs to fail at 85%. Any way I can put this together?

Comment: Welcome. Do you already tried something? Besides describing this, please also add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [OR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en) and [AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) functions

`=IF(OR(AND(R2<0.85, OR(I2="T1", I2="T2", I2="T3")), AND(R2<0.95, I2="Broker Audit")), "FAIL", "PASS")`